# Может ли ModelView иметь ссылку на View в реализации паттерна MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пишу программу на WPF, с использованием паттерна MVVM.
Мне нужно изменить из ModelView определенное свойство кнопки, описанной во View (в XAML). Но для этого необходимо хранить в ModelView ссылку на View.
Позволяет ли паттерн MVVM так делать? Будет ли это хорошим решением? Если нет, то как правильно это реализовать (как работать с элементами управления окна в ModelView)?

Comment: Вам не кто не запрещает сделать то, что вы хотите, все паттерны являются лишь рекомендациями, не более. Если следовать строго правилам MVVM, то работа с View частью из кода является нарушением, ибо сама суть MVVM в разделение всего на три мало связанных слоя. Другими словами у вас программа должна по сути запуститься вовсе без какого либо интерфейса. Что касается изменения свойство кнопки - это View часть, а значит и изменять эти свойства надо в XAML при помощи триггеров. На крайний случай вы можете сделать VM кнопки, который будет описывать необходимые свойства и уже к ним привязать кнопку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Технически вас никто не ограничивает хранить во вью-модели (ModelView) ссылку на View, но это не является MVVM решением, тогда вы теряете весь смысл этого паттерна. Смысл-то всех этих архитектурных шаблонов (MVVM, MVP, MVC и т.п.) в том, чтобы отделить бизнес-логику программы и внешнее представление этой логики (интерфейс пользователя) друг от друга. Под бизнес-логикой я подразумеваю все функции, заложенные в ваше приложение. С отделением друг от друга сложнее понимается на первых порах, но я попробую объяснить зачем это делается и возможно вы поймете сами.

Бизнес очень нетерпелив и практически всегда требует, чтобы все работало "ещё вчера". Особенно актуально это с вопросами "а мы хотим чтобы и на андройде работало и на айфоне, и на линуксе, и на виндоусе, и на маке". На каждой из этих систем свои средства для построения графических интерфейсов пользователя, что очень печально. Это необходимо под каждую систему писать свой пользовательский интерфейс. И вот представьте, что вам необходимо в кратчайшие сроки напилить приложение под все эти системы. MVVM предполагает, что ваши ModelView и Model кросплатформенны, т.е. это простой код, который работает со стандартными библиотечными типами, файлами, возможно отправляет запросы в БД, работает с XML и тому подобное, т.е. решает поставленные задачи с помощью стандартных средств, которые есть абсолютно на каждой ОС и наборе инструментов разработчика. А теперь вы начинаете хранить в предполагаемой кроссплатформенной части ссылку (т.е. явно заданный тип переменной) на View. Этим вы загнали себя в угол. Ваш код для этой ModelView теперь будет работать только на той системе, для которой эта ссылка актуально, т.е. где есть этот тип. Вот то самое зло от которого пытаются избавиться разработчики. Если вы взглянете на любую картинку, которая иллюстрирует MVVM-паттерн, то вы там увидите в большинстве случаев, что стрелочки идут от View до ModelView, а не наоборот. Отсюда получается, что только View может иметь ссылки на ModelView. И теперь получается следующее, на каждой системе написан свой графический интерфейс, который ссылается на ModelView, но Model и ModelView для всех этих систем одинаковый (экономия времени и сил, не нужно писать под каждую систему!), разные только View, которые для каждой ОС разные. И теперь получается, чтобы ваше приложение заработало на другой ОС - вам нужно всего лишь написать код графического интерфейса и все. Это смысл MVVM.

Теперь вопрос о том как это предполагается делать. Microsoft в своих технологиях базируются от интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged. Это, можно сказать, основа всего MVVM. Прочтите статью на википедии про MVVM и вы увидите там фразу "есть связывание данных". Это так называемые биндинги, которые присутствуют в XAML. Биндинг, грубо говоря, это объект, который позволяет связать 2 переменные между собой и обеспечивать в них одинаковое значения. Программирование в связке WPF + XAML предполагает, что у вашей ModelView есть публичные свойства и команды (см. ICommand), которые биндятся на свойства элементов управления (они же ещё называются контролы). Но не на каждое свойство можно забиндиться, а только на свойство зависимости (DependencyProperty). Это я вам советую уточнить в документации или в каких-либо книгах.

Вообще, вся логика пользовательского интерфейса реализуется с помощью каких-то действий в зависимости от того какое свойство изменилось и команд (они же кнопки или элементы меню).

Резюмируя и отвечая на ваши вопросы получаем, что паттерн MVVM не позволяет так делать, это будет плохим решением. Правильно реализовать свойство во ModelView и привязать это свойство к свойству кнопки.

Comment: Ссылку на View можно и нужно сделать ссылкой на интерфейс IView, в кот. можно объявить весь нужный функционал, а потом уже этот интерфейс можно реализовывать хоть в WPF, хоть в Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Насчет этого я спорить не буду, на мой взгляд немного противоречит идеологии, но да ладно. Могу сказать только то, что в этом случае придется придумать контракт интерфейса IView и чтобы он вас полностью устраивал и был полным.

Comment: В случае MVVM существует много предрассудков. Эта борьба за "природную чистоту" реализации паттерна напоминает порой религиозные войны. Для меня лично, правильная реализация ViewModel заключается только в одном -- смогу ли я покрыть юнит-тестами её функциональность, т.е. в ней нет никакой прямой зависимости от классов реализующих визуальный интерфейс приложения. Если смогу, то все правильно и об остальном я париться не собираюсь. Конечно, есть еще работодатель со своими представлениями о правильности..., но это уже др.история.

Comment: @Bulson Это будет уже не MVVM. вьюмодель не должна знать про вид больше, чем как выразить в **своем** состоянии нужное для вида "что отображать" и поменьше знать про "как отображать" и отображают ли его вообще.. Интерфейс можно, но он должен быть абстрагирован от знания про вид. Например не IView.ShowMessageBox(), а какой-нибудь INotifyService, пусть хоть там тот же вид.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых не ModelView, а ViewModel)

ViewModel не может иметь ссылку на View.

Для этой задачи вам во ViewModel нужно создать какое-то свойство для этой кнопки, и подключиться к нему с помощью biding во View.